# Display marker with x y coordinates in map with React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can only add latitude and longitude to display the marker on the map.

I have x y coordinates in my Json-file.

"gpsx":6393010,"gpsy":1650572

What is the syntax to display the marker on the map with x y coordinates in React JS?

The only thing I find is Point to use x y. But haven't get it to work.

The code is:

````
import './App.css';
import L from 'leaflet';
import pin from './images/pin.png'
import * as customerData from './data/projects.json'
import { Map, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet';

const myIcon = new L.Icon({
  iconUrl: pin,
  iconSize: [35,55],
  iconAnchor: [0, 0],
  popupAnchor: [20, -10],

})


class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    lat: 58.403503,
    lng: 15.643038,
    zoom: 9,
  }


  render() {
    const position = [this.state.lat, this.state.lng]
    return (


      <Map className="map" center={position} zoom={this.state.zoom}>
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />

        {customerData.default.map(customer => 

        <Marker position={customer.gpsx, customer.gpsy} icon={myIcon}>
          <Popup>
            A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
          </Popup>
        </Marker>)}
      </Map>


  );
  }

}

export default App;  ```
````

Comment: how do the x,y coords look like?

Comment: "gpsx":6393010,"gpsy":1650572

Answer (score 0):

You will need to "unproject" the already-projected XY coordinates to latitude and longitude.

The XY coordinates you have aren't standardized and may be using a different projection. If you want to convert XY to latitude and longitude, you can do it like so:

```js
import L from 'leaflet';

const pXY = L.point(x, y);
const position = L.Map.unproject(pXY);

// unproject accepts a second parameter, zoom. Maybe changing the value of it could help.
```

Comment: Tried to implement it without success. My goal is to show many pins with different x, y coordinates on the map. Do you know the best way to implement it in the code above?

Comment: You could map your array of x, y coordinates and return position, but since the unproject function does not return a correct value then we may not be able to do that. Working without a clearly set projection is hard when it comes to geographic data.